# Is this innodb gap lock bug?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

[image]

trx1
select * from table where refId=4 for update

trx2
insert into table (refId) values (2); block

trx2 will be blocked, i knew trx1 will keep it gap lock, [1,4),[4,7);

my question is why keep gap lock? "insert val 2" is not conflict "select where refId=4 for update", why innodb will keep gap lock,  why not use record-lock?

this question has been bothering me for a long time, please tech god save me.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

The gap lock is needed to avoid [phantom rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html).
MySQL works in REPEATABLE-READ isolation level by default. If you run several times `select ... for update` in your transaction, it should always return same result.
Suppose you don't have gap lock and trx2 inserted another row with refId=4 (index is not unique).
Then following select in trx1 will return two rows:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from t1 where refId=4 for update;
+----+------+
| id | refId|
+----+------+
|  2 |    4 |
|  4 |    4 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It is not the same result as first select.

Comment: yes, that's right, void phantom rows, as follow your test,  insert another row with refId=4, as long as trx1 keep the row record lock(or not gap lock), you can block insert refId=4, and void phantom rows; my question why keep gap lock to block insert refId=1,2,3,5,6, not only 4. feel this is mysql bug?

Comment: I think gap-lock work on this sql "select * from table where refId < 10 for update", gap-lock will block insert refId=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 to void phantom rows; it should work range search condition, not equals condition.

Answer (score 0):

> i knew trx1 will keep it gap lock, [1,4),[4,7)

Actually, to be precise in the case of a non-unique index there will be `(1,4]` 'next-key' lock (record + preceding gap) and `(4,7)` 'gap' lock before record `7`. You can check it using [`InnoDB monitor`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-standard-monitor.html).

> "insert val 2" is not conflict "select where refId=4 for update", why innodb will keep gap lock, why not use record-lock?

Gap locks purpose is to prevent records inserts into those gaps. I'm pretty sure it doesn't really check or care what `refId` of a record is when you try to insert it into a locked gap. So the point is a gap is locked and nothing can be inserted there.

Now, why do we need to lock these specific gaps? Let's imagine we're going to insert a new record with `refId = 4`, it can apparently be inserted after the existing `refId = 4` record (i.e. `(4,7)` gap) or before it (i.e. `(1,4)` gap). So if we lock just the record and don't lock these gaps it'll be possible to insert such rows.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB [test]> select * from t1 where refId=4 for update;
+----+------+
| id | refId|
+----+------+
|  2 |    aaaaa |
|  4 |    bbbbb |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

if refId is string not int, how to gap lock under RR mode in Mysql?